# Accessing parent controller in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have directive that dynamically sets the header bar content for a given application state.

I would like to be able to access the functions and variables in the Controller of the current view, but I am only ever able to access my `RootCtrl`.

The directive looks like this.

```
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: "<div ng-include='getState()'></div>",
    transclude: true,
    scope: false,
    controller: ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        //some logic to retrieve and return the correct header template html
    }],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log(scope.test);
        console.log(scope.test2);
    }
}
```

And the controllers.

```
.controller('RootCtrl', function($scope, $state, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.test = 'hello';
    //...
})

.controller('ContactsCtrl', function($scope, $state, CustomerService) {
    console.log('Contacts init');
    $scope.test2 = 'hello 2';
    //...
})
```

And when I navigate to the `contacts` state, the output looks like this.

```
hello
undefined
Contacts init
```

What should I do if I want to be able to access the `test2` variable?

Comment: Since you are not create a isolated scope you should be able to access the implementation of all controler defined in parent hierarchy. ContactsCtrl maybe defined outside the html hierarchy. You need to use share service or $rootScope to share data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `require` property inside your directive.
This will make the scope of the defined controllers available inside the link function as 4th argument. You can access the scopes as an array inside the link function then.

Your code may look like:

```
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: "<div ng-include='getState()'></div>",
    transclude: true,
    scope: false,
    require:['^RootCtrl', '^ContactsCtrl'], 
    controller: ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        //some logic to retrieve and return the correct header template html
    }],
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, requiredControllers){
        console.log(requiredControllers[0].test);
        console.log(requiredControllers[1].test2);
    }
}
```

See the Angular documentation for [Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for some more examples (under the title *Creating Directives that Communicate*) and the explanation of the `^controller` syntax.